# How can I render a field based on the value of another field

Tags: entities, theming

I set up a boolean field and an image field. I want to display the logo when the page is viewed only when the boolean field is checked. 
Below is the code that I am working with in a node template file.

```
<?php
      // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      hide($content['field_boolean']);
      hide($content['field_logo']);
      print render($content);
    ?>
  <?php if ($content['field_boolean']['und'][0]['value'] == '1'): ?>
    <?php print render($content['field_logo']); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: it is question?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$logo = render($content['field_logo']);
hide($content['field_logo']);
// ...
<?php if ($content['field_boolean']['und'][0]['value'] == '1'): ?>
  <?php print $logo; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

At the moment you're hiding the logo field, which will probably prevent it from being rendered at all, even the second time you call `render()`. Taking a copy of the rendered logo field and outputting it later should work instead.

You could also do it this way:

```
<?php if ($content['field_boolean']['und'][0]['value'] == '1'): ?>
  <?php 
  show($content['field_logo']);
  print render($content['field_logo']); 
  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error *Notice: Undefined index: field_boolean in include() (line 110

Comment: that would have been helpful information in your original post....which is suggesting that your field name is slightly off here...throw in the ever and oft suggested print_r($content) to find out what it is and you should be all set.

Comment: Yes, the filed name was off. Now I see the following error *Undefined index: und in include() (line 111

Comment: try `if ($node->field_field_name['und'][0]['value'] == '1'):` instead

Answer (score 1):

first in node tpl try to print_r($node) to check value of boolean
and try this

```
<?php
      // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      hide($content['field_boolean']);
      hide($content['field_logo']);
      print render($content);
    ?>
  <?php if ($node->field_boolean['und'][0]['value'] == '1'): ?>
    <?php print render($content['field_logo']); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: if it does not work tell me the error I think $node->field_boolean['und'][0]['value'] == '1' will work not $content->field_boolean['und'][0]['value'] == '1'

Comment: so why -1 for my answer

Answer (score 1):

@Ahmed voted your answer up again because it’s correct. In order to ensure the field is really initialized and available you would use PHPs isset function like so.

```
<?php

  if (isset($node->field_boolean['und'][0]['value']) && $node->field_boolean['und'][0]['value'] === '1') {
    echo render($content['field_logo'];
  }
```

This code is also faster because it does not open and close the PHP tags all the time (and prints the spaces) and it uses echo instead of print. And I mean much faster, test it yourself with the following code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

define('ITERATIONS', 1000000);

$node = (object)array('field_boolean');
$node->field_boolean = array('und' => array(0 => array('value' => '1')));

$before1 = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < ITERATIONS; ++$i) {
?>
  <?php if ($node->field_boolean['und'][0]['value'] == '1'): ?>
    <?php /* Do something */ ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php
}

$after1 = microtime(true);

$before2 = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < ITERATIONS; ++$i) {
  if (isset($node->field_boolean['und'][0]['value']) && $node->field_boolean['und'][0]['value'] === '1') {
    // Do something!
  }
}

$after2 = microtime(true);

echo "\n\n\n\n" . ($after1 - $before1) . ' sec1 ' . ($after2 - $before2) . ' sec2';
```

I got "18.2180221081 sec1 1.09752106667 sec2" on a simple LAMP server without any special optimizations.